# No new users made their first post today?

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign, review

I went to https://stackoverflow.com/review/ to check on some new posts, and to my surprise the page looked like this:

[image: 0 posts to review]

I got the same for week and month views; only when I clicked on "year" did I get any results. What is going on? I have that feeling that this is a caching issue, but why does it only affect certain tabs?

Comment: I see 624 first questions and 21 first answers for today.

Comment: Not sure enough to post this as answer, but I gather Stack Overflow weeks start at thursday, and december just began, so that may well be related to this.

Comment: Had you already reviewed them?

Comment: I've seen this too from time to time, just as a sanity check.  Seems to be an intermittent thing.

Comment: @balpha I get 17/17/17/110423 for first answers day/week/month/year

Answer (score 3):

You just were too slow, somebody else already reviewed all of them. Just wait a few minutes and new ones should come up.

Answer (score 1):

It looks fine to me;

[image]

Comment: hence my thought of **caching**