# There are no questions with an active bounty at the moment

Tags: bug, status-norepro, bounties, bountied-tab

I stumbled upon some odd behavior that looks like an intermittent bug to me.

On two separate occasions (only a few minutes apart, but it was working fine in the meantime), once on page 15 and once on page 16 of the bounty questions, I got the message

> There are no questions with an active bounty at the moment.

Needless to say, that was not the case.

I took a screenshot when it happened first:

[image: Bounty questions bug]

Direct link to the site: [stackoverflow.com/questions?page=15&sort=featured&pagesize=15](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?page=15&sort=featured&pagesize=15)

It is working fine right now.

**Update:**

Every time it happens, it seems to affect **all** pages from the 15th to the last, but only those.

**Update:**

The reviews page seems to be affected by the same bug: [No new users made their first post today?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114543/no-new-users-made-their-first-post-today)

Comment: Note that the direct link works only for users who view 15 items per page.  Otherwise it's a 404.

Comment: Ah, I can now reliably reproduce this.  Go to the first page of featured questions, change how many to display per page, go to the last page of questions (19 in the screenshot).  If you page back through the results the problem will "go away" but will happen again next time you follow these steps.

Comment: Aw, now it's fixed.  Maybe the SO team just fixed it?

Comment: I thought 15 per page was default. I changed the link to make `pagesize=15` explicit.

Comment: It is, but it seems to be permanently overridden per user until explicitly told otherwise (such as with your updated link).

Comment: *Aw, now it's fixed.* It is intermittent. Sometimes it works, sometimes it does not.

Comment: At first glance this reminded me of [What exactly is wrong with page 14](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109528/what-exactly-is-wrong-with-page-14), but the description and resolution there don't really match this behavior.

Comment: http://shouldiblamecaching.com

Comment: @Oded [meta-tag:status-by-cache] would be awesome new tag.

Comment: @Sha - problem with that, is that if you want to update it...