# There are no questions with an active bounty at the moment. :What to do?

Tags: bug, bountied-tab

**Edited**.

That a strange behaviour:

Near this: [There are no questions with an active bounty at the moment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114906/there-are-no-questions-with-an-active-bounty-at-the-moment) but in first page.

The red indicator stand `there is 3 active bounties` but the pages response said `0` as title of this:

[image]

In fact this seem not very harming.

So, my next question: Do I need to report this kind of bug?

If yes, where?

Comment: I was going to suggest maybe your ignored tags, but you don't appear to be logged in?  In any case, I see 3 questions when I look at it right now, so I can't reproduce.

Comment: I just saw a very similar bug with the questions page (0 questions) on Board Games.SE and Unix.SE, but I deleted my bug report, since it fixed itself.

Comment: My (deleted) bug report was here (maybe viewable by 10Ks?): http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161565/empty-question-view-on-boardgames-and-unix-sites

Comment: It may be related to [sticky tabs](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10923/eliminate-sticky-tabs).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a few moments there were no questions at all:

[image]

This happens every now and then, and although I'm not 100% about the cause I've noticed that the behaviour coincides with a system update (which was the case today as well). Everything is back to normal now, and if these brief issues are indeed because of system updates, then they are to be expected and there's nothing to worry about.

Comment: Ok thank! In fact this seem not very harming. My next question: Do I need to report this kind of bug? and if yes, where?

Comment: If you see it, give it some time. No need to rush for "bugs" that might resolve themselves given some time. But if it persists, Meta would be the right place to report them. I have to disagree with Yannis though. Please do panic! ;)

Comment: If system updates cause huge functional outages like this, then the relevant pages should be _disabled_ with _friendly notices_ for the duration, instead of just silently breaking in such a catastrophic fashion. That's _fundamental_.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Catastrophic fashion? How's not seeing the question list for five - ten minutes catastrophic?

Comment: With the exception of 'unanswered', zero questions on a public site is quite exceptional and probably does warrant some kind of 'A system update is in progress, please try again in a few minutes' message. But I wouldn't call it catastrophic, more like rough around the edges. If people shouldn't worry and try to do helpful things like report it, then it's nice to tell them that.

Comment: @Yannis: Within those five-ten minutes it's pretty catastrophic. If you're adding the duration into the mix then, yes, twenty minutes would be _more_ catastrophic.