# ORLY? No unanswered jQuery or JavaScript questions?

Tags: support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Eliminate sticky tabs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10923/eliminate-sticky-tabs)

I am impressed but incredulous

https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/javascript+or+jquery

just gave me

[image]

Ah, that was better.. A glitch?

[image]

Comment: URL? I don't see that.

Comment: Apologies: http://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/javascript+or+jquery

Comment: as if millions of questions suddenly cried out in terror and were suddenly silenced.

Comment: LOL, 90K is more like it but yes

Comment: Probably a duplicate of [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/161568/162704), there was a system update earlier today.

Comment: The implicit answer is always "use more jquery". So nothing is truly unanswered. :p