# strange behavior on Academia.SE meta

Tags: bug, status-norepro

I just went to the [Academia meta site](http://meta.academia.stackexchange.com), and I was greeted with an empty page:

[image: empty academia meta]

Clicking on one of the meta questions in the "community bulletin" sidebar brought me to an actual question, but nothing is showing up for me when I visit the main page. Bug? Temporary glitch?

FWIW, the screenshot is from 1/26/2013 at 9:40:32 PM from Safari with the following user agent string:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_2) AppleWebKit/536.26.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0.2 Safari/536.26.17
```

Comment: It's probably this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/161573/162704 - Don't worry about it, your Meta will come back in a few minutes.

Comment: Right after I read this question, [this happened here on MSO](http://i.stack.imgur.com/TDrlj.png).

Comment: Happened to me a couple of minutes ago too on MSO

Comment: I saw it on MSO, and on travel it persisted through a refresh, though a second one brought the whole site back

Comment: Happened for a while on physics, code-golf and skeptics, too. Several refreshes.

Comment: I saw this bug a little while ago on the Science Fiction site, and I'm still seeing it on the (private beta) English Language Learners site.

Comment: On SO I see the last question as "1 hour ago". I can follow links to newer questions if given one, but I cannot find them in the question lists. Is this related, or should I open a new question here on MSO?

Comment: People are talking about this being down to system updates. But if a system update can cause a massive functional outage like this, then the same system update should involve _disabling_ the affected page(s) for the duration with a _friendly, explanatory message_, instead of simply ceasing to work at all.

Comment: Same thing happening on Arqade http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/6812/is-arqade-broken-right-now