# No more questions on stackoverflow?

Tags: bug, stack-overflow

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [strange behavior on Academia.SE meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165212/strange-behavior-on-academia-se-meta)

**Before you downvote a seemingly evil duplicate:** I actually tried to search for a similar issue on meta before posting this but even the search results are delayed by up to an hour.

Every question has been answered?

[image: All questions answered]

0 questions tagged with [php] on stackoverflow? This can't be real. And it does take quite a while to load this "no results" page.

[image: 0 questions tagged with php]

Same thing goes here.

[image: No questions with active bounty]

Comment: same general issue as [strange behavior on Academia.SE meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165212/strange-behavior-on-academia-se-meta)

Comment: ... and with the [tag:java] tagged questions on stackoverflow. The server must be having problems.

Comment: @waiwai933 I couldn't search for a similar issue during the time when this occurred since strange things happened on meta stackoverflow too.

Comment: yep, just had the problem here on Meta.